# Query to Select User Start/End datetime fall in datetime range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I has two table which table ResourceAssign is store employee work shift.  Another table is store the item processing datetime.  Below is the script for create the table and the sample data.

```
GO
```

/****** Object: Table [dbo].[ResourceAssign] Script Date: 04/07/2015 09:05:35 ******/

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceAssign](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ResourceID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Inactive] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ResourceAssign] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =      
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO [ResourceAssign]
([ResourceID],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Inactive])VALUES
('I0109', '2015-03-30 08:30:00.000',    '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0104',   '2015-03-30 08:30:00.000',  '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-03-30 08:30:00.000',  '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0109',   '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000',  '2015-03-31 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000',  '2015-03-31 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-03-30 16:30:00.000',  '2015-03-31 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0109',   '2015-03-31 08:30:00.000',  '2015-03-31 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-03-31 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-03-31 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0109',   '2015-04-01 00:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000', 0),
('I0104',   '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 00:30:00.000', 0),
('I0104',   '2015-04-02 00:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 08:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-04-02 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0109',   '2015-04-02 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0104',   '2015-04-03 00:30:00.000',  '2015-04-03 08:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-04-03 00:30:00.000',  '2015-04-03 08:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-04-03 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-03 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0109',   '2015-04-03 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-04 00:30:00.000', 0)
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuantityProcess](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Length1] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[Length2] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[LengthMeterSqr] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
[TotalLength] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
[StartProcessTime] [datetime] NULL,
[EndProcessTime] [datetime] NULL,
[DurationUse] [nchar](10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_QuantityProcess] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     
OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [inno_Edging].[dbo].[QuantityProcess]
([Length1],[Length2],[LengthMeterSqr],[TotalLength],[StartProcessTime]
,[EndProcessTime]
,[DurationUse])VALUES
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-01 16:30:19.000',  '2015-04-  
 01 16:30:52.000',  33), 
(224.00,    294.00, 0.0659, 1036.00, '2015-04-01 16:31:08.000', '2015-04-  
01 16:32:06.000',   58), 
(226.00,    224.00, 0.0506, 900.00, '2015-04-01 16:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:36:05.000',   29), 
(223.00,    221.00, 0.0493, 888.00, '2015-04-01 16:32:16.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:34:21.000',   125),
(228.00,    228.00, 0.0520, 912.00, '2015-04-01 18:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:37:36.000',   120), 
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-01 18:38:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:40:36.000',   120), 
(228.00,    228.00, 0.0520, 912.00, '2015-04-02 08:58:49.000',  '2015-04-
02 08:59:35.000',   46), 
(230.00,    229.00, 0.0527, 918.00, '2015-04-02 08:59:43.000',  '2015-04-
02 09:04:09.000',   266), 
(226.00,    227.00, 0.0513, 906.00, '2015-04-02 09:04:19.000',  '2015-04-
02 09:05:37.000',   78), 
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-02 00:10:36.000',  '2015-04-
02 00:11:36.000',   60) , 
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-02 00:13:36.000',  '2015-04- 
02 00:15:36.000',   120),
(223.00,    223.00, 0.0497, 892.00, '2015-04-02 09:57:39.000',  '2015-04-
02 09:57:46.000',   7), 
(233.00,    233.00, 0.0543, 932.00, '2015-04-02 12:59:27.000',  '2015-04-
02 13:00:18.000',   51), 
(229.00,    232.00, 0.0531, 922.00, '2015-04-02 13:02:02.000',  '2015-04-
02 13:02:55.000',   53), 
(216.00,    217.00, 0.0469, 866.00, '2015-04-03 11:15:08.000',  '2015-04-
03 11:15:45.000',   37), 
(326.00,    220.00, 0.0717, 1092.00,    '2015-04-03 11:15:53.000',   
'2015-04-03 11:16:13.000',  20), 
(258.00,    329.00, 0.0849, 1174.00,    '2015-04-03 11:16:25.000',  
'2015-04-03 11:16:40.000',  15), 
(233.00,    214.00, 0.0499, 894.00, '2015-04-03 12:15:20.000',  '2015-04-
03 12:15:30.000',   10), 
(321.00,    229.00, 0.0735, 1100.00,    '2015-04-06 15:09:20.000',  
'2015-04-06 15:09:27.000',  7)
```

In my system, user allow to select a start datetime and end datetime to get the result. User can select start date 2015-04-01 16:31:00 and end date 2015-04-01 19:30:00 from the system to find out what item is process in this datetime range. With the same datetime range, user need to know who is assign to process this item. The resource(employee) is assign base on the shift(8 hour per shift). So, if user select start date 2015-04-01 16:31:00 and end date 2015-04-01 19:30:00 to query the item process, they also need to know whose in that period in charge to process the item with the time range select. How I can get result the datetime user select is fall in which shift?

The result expected are

**Quantity Process table**

```
(224.00,    294.00, 0.0659, 1036.00, '2015-04-01 16:31:08.000', '2015-04-
 01 16:32:06.000',  58), 
(226.00,    224.00, 0.0506, 900.00, '2015-04-01 16:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:36:05.000',   29), 
(223.00,    221.00, 0.0493, 888.00, '2015-04-01 16:32:16.000',  '2015-04- 
01 16:34:21.000',   125),
(228.00,    228.00, 0.0520, 912.00, '2015-04-01 18:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:37:36.000',   120), 
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-01 18:38:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:40:36.000',   120),
```

**Resource Assign table**

('I0108',   '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 00:30:00.000', 0)

Another scenario is if user select date range is start date 2015-04-01 00:00:01 and end date 2015-04-01 23:59:59, the result expected as below. Even only 1-4-2015 16:30:19 - 1-4-2015 18:40:36 has item process, but there is few shift or employee is fall in the time range user selected. It also need to been query out as a result for Resource assign table.

**Quantity Process table**

```
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-01 16:30:19.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:30:52.000',   33), 
(224.00,    294.00, 0.0659, 1036.00, '2015-04-01 16:31:08.000', '2015-04-
01 16:32:06.000',   58), 
(226.00,    224.00, 0.0506, 900.00, '2015-04-01 16:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:36:05.000',   29), 
(223.00,    221.00, 0.0493, 888.00, '2015-04-01 16:32:16.000',  '2015-04-
01 16:34:21.000',   125),
(228.00,    228.00, 0.0520, 912.00, '2015-04-01 18:35:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:37:36.000',   120), 
(223.00,    219.00, 0.0488, 884.00, '2015-04-01 18:38:36.000',  '2015-04-
01 18:40:36.000',   120),
```

**Resource Assign table**

```
('I0109',   '2015-04-01 00:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000', 0),
('I0104',   '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0107',   '2015-04-01 08:30:00.000',  '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000', 0),
('I0108',   '2015-04-01 16:30:00.000',  '2015-04-02 00:30:00.000', 0),
```

Any idea how I can get this result?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the list of `Resources` where the resource satisfies one of the below

1. the entire shift in within the start and end range passed
2. the shift starts before the range and ends after the range has started
3. the shift starts after the range has started and ends after the range end

   ```
   DECLARE @Startdate DATETIME = '2015-04-01 16:31:00'
   DECLARE @Enddate DATETIME = '2015-04-01 19:30:00'
   --SELECT @Startdate  = '2015-04-01 00:00:01',@Enddate = '2015-04-01 23:59:59'
   SELECT * FROM ResourceAssign
       WHERE (StartDate <= @Startdate AND EndDate >= @Enddate)
       OR (StartDate <=@Startdate AND Enddate >= @Startdate )
       OR (StartDate <=@Enddate AND EndDate >=@Enddate)

   SELECT * FROM QuantityProcess
   WHERE (StartProcessTime >=@Startdate AND EndProcessTime <= @Enddate)
   ```

You can uncomment the `SELECT` to get the output for second example.